# Values of this integeration

Tags: integration

The values of $$I=\int_{0}^{1} {x^4} ({1-x})^4\dfrac1{1+x^2}dx$$
My Failed Attempt

I tried applying F(x)  =F(a+b-x)  in hopes the denominator will cancel out but it's not. I tried to further simplify the expression but with no luck

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} {x^4} ({1-x})^4\dfrac1{1+({1-x})^2}dx$$

Adding both integral isn't helping me much

Comment: This is one that you just do, rather than look for clever tricks. It has an amusing answer.

Comment: Already asked in [2012](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129625/finding-int-01-fracx41-x41x2dx), [2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450910/shortest-method-for-int-01-fracx4-left1-x-right41x2), [2016](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614676/creative-way-for-int-0-1-fracx4-1-x4-x2-1-rm-dx), [2017](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084526/evaluating-int-01-fracx4-1-x41x2-dx). See also [Proof that $22/7$ exceeds $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^1 x^4(1-x)^4\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$

First compute the integral without boundaries $$\int x^4(1-x)^4\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Apply long division on $\dfrac{x^4(1-x)^4}{x^2+1}$ and we get in the form of $x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\dfrac{4}{x^2+1}$

Now you can easily compute the integral $$\int x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2+4-\dfrac{4}{x^2+1}\ dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Use that $$\frac {x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}={x}^{6}-4\,{x}^{5}+5\,{x}^{4}-4\,{x}^{2}+4-4\, \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{-1}
$$

Comment: Just check the edit. The difference between the two integrals is large.

Comment: How did you simply this expression... Did you open up the terms

Comment: It is the partial fractur decomposition of your integrand